# How to get data from csv file based on first column name using java

Tags: java, csv, selenium-webdriver

In attached csv image I am trying to fetch the data and store it hashmap based on testcase name which is in first column. And in second column I have given rowcount value which says number of test data available for that particular testcase, so that I can get the value of rowcount and loop it for that many times to get all those data available for that particular testcase. I have written the code to get the value of rowcount. But I do no how to fetch the data for that particular test and store it in hashmap.

[Click here to view CSV File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrUW8.png)

```
String path = "./TestData.csv";
String TestCaseName="Login";
String CurrentLine;

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String Data[] = CurrentLine.split(",");
        if(TestCaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(Data[0])){
            System.out.println("Details in this row :"+ "  " +CurrentLine);
            String rowcount_value = Data[1];
            System.out.println(rowcount_value);
        }
    }
}       
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the attached csv image I wanted to fetch data for Testcase Login, So I gave Testcase name as Login in the above code. And now I want to fetch all the highlighted data in the image which belongs to Login testcase and store it in a hashmap. The above code just gives the rowcount value of the passed testcase name.

Please help me to fetch those highlighted data and store it in hashmap. I am new to this field and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As your csv file is having fixed number of data points for different test cases, you may need to update the below code in case of adding more test cases.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReadCsv {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String path = "sample.csv";
//  String TestCaseName="Login";
    String CurrentLine;

    //Map to store TestCase -> Map(Key ->value)

    Map<String,Map<String,String>> testcaseMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String,String>>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        br.readLine();
        while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String Data[] = CurrentLine.trim().split(",");
            String testCase_DataNames = "";
            for(int j=2;j<Data.length;j++){
                testCase_DataNames = testCase_DataNames +"_"+Data[j];
            }
            int dataCount = Integer.parseInt(Data[1]);
            Map<String,String> testdata = new HashMap<String,String>();
            for(int i=0;i<dataCount;i++){
                String nextLine = br.readLine();
                String feilds[] = nextLine.trim().split(",");
                testdata.put(feilds[2], feilds.length ==4 ? feilds[3]:null);

            }
            testcaseMap.put(Data[0]+testCase_DataNames, testdata);
            /*if(TestCaseName.equalsIgnoreCase(Data[0])){
                System.out.println("Details in this row :"+ "  " +CurrentLine);
                String rowcount_value = Data[1];
                System.out.println(rowcount_value);
            } */
        }


        for(Map.Entry<String,Map<String,String>> entry:testcaseMap.entrySet()){
             String key[] = entry.getKey().split("_");
            System.out.println("Test case for:"+key[0]);

                for(Map.Entry<String, String> dataPair: entry.getValue().entrySet()){
                    System.out.println("Data header:"+key[1]+" with value:"+dataPair.getKey());
                    if(dataPair.getValue()!= null ) {
                        System.out.println("Data header:"+key[2]+" with value:"+dataPair.getValue());
                    }

            }

        }
    }       
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
Test case for:Login
Data header:UserName  with value:uname2
Data header:Password with value:pwd2
Data header:UserName  with value:uname1
Data header:Password with value:pwd1
Test case for:Hotel
Data header:HotelNames with value:Ambur
Data header:HotelNames with value:BlackPerl
Data header:HotelNames with value:Zingro
```

Hope this will work for you ! Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot Nagaraj, It works as per the requirement.

Comment: Kamal - Please accept the answer and upvote. Enjoy !